# why you need to throw exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I don't know, why you need to throw exception in java. I can just evaluate the return value. Here is an example:

```
int logic(int i){
      switch(i){
           case 0:
           return 0;
           case 1:
           return 1;
           default:
           throw new Exception();
           // return -1;
      }
}
```

In the case of default, I can throw exception object, but I can also can return -1. The two methods can capture it. Why do I need to throw an exception?
My English is not that great, because English is not my main language. If there are something you do not understand, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: You throw an exception to convey that, **a critical problem has occurred** to the caller of your method

Comment: I don't see why would you `throw` an *exception* there.

Comment: no need to use exception here....default put into the break

Comment: pass "abc" instead of an int when calling your "logic()" method... There you will get to know why you need exception... Or you could try returning "abc" instead of 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception, in suitable cases, has several advantages:

In some cases every possible value of the return type is a meaningful result. There is no spare value to use to represent an error.

An exception can convey a lot more information. It can include a message explaining what went wrong.

Catching exceptions can be done for a block of code. Testing return values has to be done after every call, cluttering the code.

An exception can be passed up the call stack to a method that can better report or process it than the immediate caller.

Comment: Good summary. The only one missing is that it is even more efficient if not every caller in a chain has to check return values for error markers.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know, why need exception in java.

Exceptions are used as an indication of run-time failure. For example: Some I/O operation cannot be performed or specified resource is not available. In such cases, JVM will indicate the failure by the means of exceptions.

Throwing exceptions is one thing and handling them is another. In your case you are considering a situation where you are explicitly throwing exception. But what if JVM needs to throw one. There is no mechanism to return values via. JVM.

> In the case of default, I can return a value

When you explicitly throw an checked exception, the caller has to either handle it or throw it. As a result, caller is aware that the method is capable of generating exception and it can take appropriate actions to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two types of Exception namely `Checked` and `Unchecked`. No need worry to handle `Unchecked` `Exception`. But need to handle `Checked` `Exception`.

**Why do we need checked exception in Java?**

> Checked exceptions are as much part of your method signature as the
>   name of the method and its parameters so the exception is part of the
>   contract that you have with the client code. They serve as a marker to
>   the client code that you have come across a error situation that you
>   do not know how to handle or that you want the client code to know
>   about so that it can handle the problem for you.

[Read more.](https://wikis.oracle.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=30146595)

Answer (score 0):

An `exception` is used to denote a situation in which something *exceptional*, if you will, has happened and thus requires some special attention. You can return different integer values to denote the terminating state of the different methods you have, but what if you have a method which reads an object from file and returns it?

Your method would require you to:

1. Have your method return a list of items, thus making your code more complex.
2. Have some sort of documentation to denote what do the different numbers in your return statement mean. This can be troublesome, especially if you are not careful enough and adopt some sort of standard.

In short, if you have the same method above and use exceptions, you can return just the object you are creating while at the same time point the list of this which can go wrong in the method signature, thus making the code easier to read, follow and maintain.

In short:

```
public List loadObjectFromFile(String path)
{
     List returnList = new ArrayList();
     ...
     //Something goes wrong in your code
     returnList.add("1");
}
```

Then you call it like so:

```
List loadFromFile = loadObjectFromFile("...");
if(list.get(0).toString().equals("1"))
{
    System.out.println("Error ... has occured");
}
...
else if(list.get(0).toString().equals("0"))
{
    MyObject obb = loadFromFile.get(1);
}
```

As opposed to:

```
public MyObject LoadObject(String filePath) throws Exception
{
    ...
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
try
{
    MyObject obj = LoadObject("...");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should **never** `throw new Exception()`. This is very bad practice as it encourages catching `Exception`. This means that all exceptions are treated in the same way by the code, i.e. you catch exceptions that you didn't mean to.

So you should create a custom exception type or use one of the existing ones. Maybe something like an `IllegalArgumentException`. There is a large debate over when to throw unchecked (exceptions that extend `RuntimeException`) versus checked exceptions. I won't get into that now.

As for why you would throw an exception rather than `return -1`, this is due to the nature of exceptions. They "propagate". You can throw them in one method and they automatically get propagated up the call stack until they are caught. This means you can throw an exception in your business layer and propagate it to your GUI layer without having to explicitly `return` an error code.

Further, what happens when the error is in a `void` method:

```
void logic(int i){
      switch(i){
           case 0:
             doSomethingWonderFul();
           case 1:
             doSomethingEvenMoreWonderFul();
           default:
             //oops, what now?
      }
}
```